# Declare URL of Api once in entire Nuxt.js app

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, store

I am using a CMS to populate my Nuxt.js app and declaring the api URL as following.

in **nuxt.config.js**, to generate dynamic routes, I have:

```
  const apiUrl = 'http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx'

  generate:{
    routes: function () {
      return axios.get(apiUrl + '/pages')
        .then((res) => {
          return res.data.map(page =>{
            return page.slug
          })
      })
    }
  },
  apollo: {
    clientConfigs: {
      default: {
        httpEndpoint: apiUrl + '/graphql'
      }
    }
  }
```

in **store/index.js**, to be accessible in my layout, pages and components, I have:

```
export const state = () => ({
  apiUrl: 'http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx'
})
```

As you can see, the downside here is that the const is declared in two different places, which might be not a big deal but feels "wrong" to me. It seems not possible to get data from the store in the nuxt.config,js, and not possible to get data from nuxt.config.js into my pages/components unless importing it every time.
Is there not a more clean way to set this up, or am I doing it in the wrong way anyway?

**EDIT**

I might have also complicated my question. Basically what I need in my Layout, Pages and Components it's the pure apiURL. This is needed to be the first part of the url when I load images from the api.

I am using apollo so I get all the data with that, but the image urls are returned like `uploads/image_name.jpg`. This means that really what I need is the httpEndpoint (from the apollo settings inside nuxt.config.js) to be available in my components as part of the full images url.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is an environment variable.

Here it is described in more detail. https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-env/

What I prefer over it is the .dotenv module https://github.com/nuxt-community/dotenv-module

You would simply make an `.env` file in the root of your project and write down:

```
API_URL=http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
```

Then you can use it everywhere in your components, pages etc. through the process and context. `this.$process.env.API_URL`

If you also wanna use that variable inside your `nuxt.config.js` you can simply `require('dotenv').config()` and use it there too.

Comment: Hi Badgy, this is the best solution in fact. I think I saw it before but though was aimed more if you have different cms for development and production (which I guess you can still benefit from this setup).
I used dotenv but `process.env.API_URL` works, while `this.$process.env.API_URL` gives me an error.

Also, by default .env gets ignored so my GitLab pipeline will fail when trying to generate static pages. Is it safe for me to commit the .env file, despite everywhere people say not to?

Comment: @Saro it depends in your case nothing in the .env is harmful if readed out so should no problem. You could also inject the url via a plugin into your context like export default ({ app }, inject) => {
  inject('API_URL', 'THEURL')
} inside your plugin file, more here https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/#combined-inject

Comment: this sounds like another viable option, but can I get the API_URL in nuxt.config.js? It works on pages with this.$API_URL but it's undefined in the config file

Comment: With Nuxt 2.13 dotenv is also not required anymore.
What I couldn't undertstand is that you need the same variable available on your repo pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

nuxt by default provides axios module with configurations to do
by using this you can easily add axios in your `nuxt.config.js` file like:

```
axios: {
    //axios options
},
```

in your case you can set base url in your `nuxt.config.js` file like this:

```
axios: {
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/'
},
```

then every request that sends with axios has baseUrl in front of it for example:

```
async asyncData({ $axios }) {
  const items = await $axios.$get('/items')
  return { items }
}
```

this code send a get request to `localhost:3000/items`

PS1: in case you want to change base url for one request you can pass full address to $get like:

```
async asyncData({ $axios }) {
  const items = await $axios.$get('http://mytestsite.com/items')
  return { items }
}
```

PS2: for more information visit [nuxt axios](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/) site

Comment: Hi and thanks! I added an edit to my original post, as using axios to get the /items seems something extra, as I use apollo to get the query. what I need in my pages it's just the baseUrl

Answer (score 0):

i think the have some updates regarding this matter.

by using a runtimeConfig ( public / private ).
https://nuxtjs.org/blog/moving-from-nuxtjs-dotenv-to-runtime-config#introducing-the-nuxtjs-runtime-config

I just stumbled this link also. hopes this help.

Im using nuxt version **2.15.7**